# How to navigate one page to another in sap fiori?

Tags: sapui5

i am new to sap fiori.Can anyone please tell me how to navigate one page to another in sap fiori?

Thanks,
Navya.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigating in SAPUI5 / Fiori applications is ideally done with a Router.
I'd suggest completing this tutorial https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/1b6dcd39a6a74f528b27ddb22f15af0d.html which explains the whole concept in depth.

Alternatively you can also add multiple pages to a NavContainer and then use its .to() function (although I would suggest using the correct routing best practise as it facilitates easier extensibility and maintainability)